# How to avoid the ssh username prompt if only ssh key is permitted

Tags: linux, ssh

I've configured a remote debian to only accept ssh login with key for a determined user, which will only use one local machine to access it.

Deactivated the root login, password login on the remote machine, however when I try to ssh from anywhere else it still ask for username and then says that there are no supported authentication methods.

Can I avoid that username prompt?

Thanks

Comment: `man ssh_config` should point you in the right direction... Especially the bits about `User`, `IdentityFile` and setting up per-destination options...

Comment: Btw, this question really belongs to Unix&Linux or superuser, not stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try editing `~/.ssh/config` as

```
host [host]
    hostname [ip]
    user [username]
```

change everything between brackets to match your needs.

Also, you should double check pub/priv keys on remote/local host.

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible ways of achieving that (**on the server**):

a) Stand up tcpwrappers for ssh and only allow connection from that one host to the ssh port.

b) Set up an iptables rule to drop connection attempts from any but the permitted machine.